# Python/PHP, cakePHP and wordpress

Tags: php, python, wordpress, cakephp

Could someone explain differences and relations between Python/PHP, cakePHP and wordpress? Maybe draw some connections to Ruby or Java? Could you compare wordpress to Google Web Toolkit?

Comment: "Please compare a penis to a slice of bacon to a snowflake to the planet Mars."

Comment: You're asking for comparisons between multiple languages, frameworks, and a content management system, all of which you could read about on Wikipedia.

Comment: @ceejayoz Oh sorry your highness, I didn't see we had a royal prick here..

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's essentially what your question is asking. The items you've laid out are not easily comparable, something that'd have been immediately obvious if you'd bothered to look them up on Wikipedia.

Comment: @ceejayoz I asked the questions here cause of the pedagogical and kind people like dqhendricks and MrGlass, they can explain faster and better than any wikipedia page. Even when a newbie of webdevelopment like me asks a question they can interpret it and still give an useful answer. That, I guess, is something you lack of, that, and sympathy. I guess you were born a senior developer.. But apology accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python and PHP are two different languages. Both are interpreted and use dynamic variable typing and automatic memory management.

cakePHP is a "Framework" for PHP. This is basically pre-existing code base that handles most of the common tasks needed for web applications.

Wordpress is an open-source CMS (Content Managament System) written in PHP. This is basically a web application that can be used to set up and manage the content of a website, although it is limited by the features already coded within Wordpress, and any Wordpress plug-ins.

Google Web Toolkit would not be compared to a CMS.

Answer (score 1):

These are all very different things. rather than compare apples and oranges, i will provide you a basic idea of what each is:

PHP - a language. Easy to deploy, easy to code in. Used in many websites

Python - A different language. Faster, not quite as easy to deploy, not quite as popular, but not hard.

CakePHP - a framework. This runs in PHP and helps build the website. Some frameworks are more like function libraries, other integrate tightly with your website.

Wordpress - a blogging platform. Easy to install, once installed you having a working website. There are plenty of themes, widgets, and plugins you can use to modify it, and you can edit the code to your tastes as well.